# How to preg_replace html tag to allow only two of theese in a row

Tags: php

I watched other topics, but didn't found an answer. So I'm using CKeditor, and I need to limit the count user could make new lines. So if user makes 4 new lines, output for this would be:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I need to block this "feature" and after preg_replace I need output like this:

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

I just can't find right regexp

Comment: You don't use regexes on html. You use [DOM](http://php.net/dom)

Comment: I get string from $_POST, where is string with <p> tags -> it's CKEditor.. I store tags in DB... I need to get rid of multiple <p>&nbsp;</p>

Comment: You can make use of string function str_replace

Comment: But 4 of these tags are not limit. How can I use str_replace if I need to leave 2 <p>&nbsp;</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following code:

```
$find = "~(?:<p>&nbsp;</p>)(?:\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>){2,}~";
$repl = "<p>&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p>&nbsp;</p>";
$html = preg_replace($find, $repl, $_POST["something"]);
```

Comment: I mean instead of PHP_EOL, maybe that's the problem, because your given example is not working

Comment: Are you sure there are both carriage return and line feed between two consecutive instances of `<p>&nbsp;</p>`? You may `base64_encode` the user-submitted string (which has two or more newlines) and then post the result here. I’ll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use str_replace function like below,

```
str_replace("<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>", "<p>&nbsp;  
</p><p>&nbsp;</p>", $content);
```

Comment: ... But if there is 6 <p>&nbsp;</p> then what? Then I guess will be 4 these <p>&nbsp;</p>